# How to initialize SPA app with backing Web API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, deployment, single-page-application

I currently have an Aurelia single page application I'm developing in WebStorm, and a backing Web API I'm developing in Visual Studio.  In the dev environment, everything works fine, I just host my client application using WebStorm's server and point it towards my local web api url.

When I deploy the application, I need a way to initiate my client, however.  Is it common practice to have my Web API's default route return my `index.html` page?  For some reason it seems very strange to me.  Is there a better way to first serve up my `index.html`?  I haven't been able to find much online regarding the subject.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in several projects is to build a single MVC + WebApi project.

This way you will be able to serve both the MVC part for your "index.html" and the WebApi for all your API needs.

So the MVC part is basically just a `DefaultController` with a `Index` method that returns the View that initializes my SPA.

In other words, the View for the `Index` method returns the content you normally would have put in your `index.html` file.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Now that you say it, it makes pretty obvious sense.  I'm using OWIN, so I grabbed the lightweight `Nancy` instead of MVC, but it does the same job.  Thanks!